# Envelope detector RC values

Tags: voltage, amplitude-modulation, demodulation, detector

I have understood how the envelope detector works, but I am unable to find the formula for R and C appropriate values. The closest I have found is this link:

[Explain The Square Law Demodulation and Envelope Demodulation of AM Wave](https://electronicspost.com/explain-the-square-law-demodulation-and-envelope-demodulation-of-am-wave/)

Any help?

Comment: You've posted a list of google results, not a link to a particular site.  That returns different results for everyone who clicks on it.  Post a direct link to whatever source you are referring to, and draw an example circuit.  Include the frequency (or frequency range) of the input signal.

Comment: There is no single formula. Think about the characteristics you want and pick RC that suits your purpose. You want an RC that accepts the highest frequency you're interested in (-3dB point higher than that frequency) and rejects the lowest frequency you want to remove (-3dB point much lower than that frequency). Usually there is a range of suitable RC values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large ratio between the highest frequency of the information, and the carrier frequency, then you might set the RC time constant at the geometric_mean midpoint between the carrier period and the information period

Thus with 1MHz carrier (AM radio) and 5MHz voice/music, thus 1uSec and 200uSec, set the RC at sqrt(1uS * 200uS) = about 15uS.

===================================

By using the geometric_mean, you have a starting point of optimization.

There will be deterministic trash on output of the RC LPF. You may want to further filter the waveform.

You may need to perform some time simulations, with diode half-wave rectifiers, and think about the residual ripple coming from the RC LPF.

Comment: Analog systems RF the information frequency is at kiloherz. Can I still use the mean midpoint?